# RailsのDeviseでフィールドを追加した時のビューの動作について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails で Devise の Gem をインストールし利用しています。

rails : 4.2.1
 devise : 3.4.1

以下のURLのように、新たに name フィールドをDBテーブルに追加して利用しました。
http://easyramble.com/add-field-devise-signup-form.html

そこでカスタムビューを作成し、「app/views/users/regsitrations/new.html.erb」の中で、「<%= f.name_field :name %>」として利用使用しようとしたところ以下のエラーとなりました。

> NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
>   undefined method `name_field' for

メソッドとして「name_field」が用意されていないという事で、上記のURLにもありますように、「<%= f.text_field :name %>」としたところ動作はしました。

ここで質問なのですが、Deviseで、「フィールド_field」の定義がどこで行われていて、text以外の定義が出来るのか教えていただきたいです。

お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text_field は form_for の機能ですので、Devise とは関係ありません。

form_for を一度調べてみてください。

[フォーム(form) - - Railsドキュメント](http://railsdoc.com/form#%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9(text_field))
[Ruby - Railsのフォーム基本的な作成方法まとめ（form_forとかform_tag） - Qiita](http://qiita.com/ykyk1218/items/2541a313aac0f0e5d81a)
[【Rails】formヘルパーを徹底的に理解する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/shunsuke227ono/items/7accec12eef6d89b0aa9)